# How do I activate an Audio file at a certian time using date object?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I want to activate an audio file every round 15 minutes using `Date Object`.

I have tried to use a `while` loop to determine the specific time but it's not working.

Comment: Code sample?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Yes, I've just posted it here in the Answers

Comment: @user3043221 you still haven't posted any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

and [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay.

I'd imagine you'll use these in conjunction with an [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element for playback.

A quick solution would be something like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LruW8/1/)):

```
(function () {
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = 900000;

    function playAudio() {
        document.getElementById('audio-test').play();
    }

    setTimeout(function () {

        playAudio();

        setInterval(playAudio, interval); // execute on interval

    }, interval - time % interval); // execute at next interval

})();
```

Perform a `setTimeout` to catch up to the next interval and then use `setInterval` after that. One caveat to this approach is that the `delay` specified for these functions is a *minimum delay*, i.e.: the *actual* delay may be longer. So, the interval could drift out of accuracy.

Alternatively, you could poll at a shorter interval and check that the minutes are evenly divided by 15. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N93d8/)

```
(function () {
    var last;
    setInterval(function(){
        var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
        if(minutes % 15 === 0 && last !== minutes){
            last = minutes;
            document.getElementById('audio-test').play();          
        }
    },1000);
})();
```

Comment: Hello,
I was reffering to how to activate it from the computer clock (date object) meaning:
Activate the audio at: 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 1:00 and so on .. 

thanks

Comment: @user3043221 please edit your question to include that information.